# Best way to make a coin pile?

Tags: texturing

Okay, here's a little something in need of a solution:

I am planning on making some piles of coins for a dragon's treasure hoard.  This would be for game content, so it would all need to be low-poly, probably as a mesh pile with a textured surface.

Is there any good way to do this that would make the pile look authentic, or at least believable?  Like, for example, would it be possible to create a particle system, and then bake its output to the surface of a mesh?  Or would there be a better way to get natural results?

EDIT 1: If possible, I'd also like to get decent normal maps for the coin pile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Model a coin (depending on how detailed you need just a short cylinder). Then use rigid body physics to drop the coins into a pile. [cg cookie tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYL9w6xsZ6g) ([archive](https://cgcookie.com/archive/using-rigid-body-physics-to-create-a-falling-buttons-image/)). After you have a pile of coins then you can [bake a normal map](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html) to a low poly mesh. Short description of the process on bottom of that page.

For the color, bake that too ([also on that page](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html)). You would want a *full render*, or a *Textures* bake for the diffuse map.

If you are using cycles, the [bake](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/baking.html) options are a little different.

Comment: Along with a diffuse map as well, aye?